# Double, XOR and do it again

Tags: code-golf, bitwise

We define the function **g** as **g(n) = n XOR (n * 2)** for any integer **n > 0**.

Given **x > 0**, find the smallest integer **y > 0** such that **g<sup>k</sup>(y) = x** for some **k > 0**.

### Example

```
x = 549

549 = 483 XOR (483 * 2)     (as binary: 1000100101 = 111100011 XOR 1111000110)
483 = 161 XOR (161 * 2)     (as binary:  111100011 =  10100001 XOR  101000010)
```

Which means that **g<sup>2</sup>(161) = 549**. We can't go any further, as there is no **n** such that **g(n) = 161**. So, the expected output for **x = 549** is **y = 161**.

### Rules

- You are not supposed to support invalid entries. A pair **(y, k)** is guaranteed to exist for the input value **x**.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

### Test cases

```
     3 -->     1
     5 -->     1
     6 -->     2
     9 -->     7
    10 -->     2
    23 -->    13
    85 -->     1
   549 -->   161
   960 -->    64
  1023 -->   341
  1155 -->   213
  1542 -->     2
  9999 -->  2819
 57308 --> 19124
 57311 -->   223
983055 -->     1
```

Comment: Related OEIS: [A048274](http://oeis.org/A048724) which is the sequence `a(n) = g(n)`

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>68</s> <s>57</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0;i<n;)i-=(i*2^i)==n?n=i:-1;return n;}
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XZFPb4JAEMXvfoqJJ6iBsCAWXbf9BPXisX@SLWIzioOBwaQhfHa6bjmw7mGSN5n3y8vbk77p4HQ4D3mpmwbeNFIHMANA4qI@6ryAXWekXUDu3Sf50mz6mRkNa8YcdkCgYKDgpTtWtT1CFUnckvQxUB4@xV/oK0WvpHATCFkX3NYEJPtB3jnX9rs0nBF3q/AAFxPF23ON9PP@Cdr/T8FFw15iA4winYrVVKynQkRTFTuIzGGkS8e4XkUux/UKkTpukS5jx26eQ39OouxhIYTjyJJoZE47tqXYA1vv2Mf@t@HiElYth1dTFZfk4WK@@eD5gkLzXf7I6Yc/)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                 // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  for(int i=0;i<n;)  //  Loop `i` in the range (1,n)
    i-=(i*2^i)==n?   //   If `i*2` XOR-ed with `i` equals `n`
        n=i          //    Set `n` to `i`, and set `i` to 0 to reset the loop
       :             //   Else:
        -1;          //    Increase `i` by 1 to go to the next iteration
  return n;}         //  Return `n` after the entire loop
```

Comment: `n->{for(int i=0;i<n;)i-=(i*2^i)==n?n=i:-1;return n;}` (52 bytes). Sorry ^^'

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Even smarter, thanks!

Comment: `for(int i=0;n>i-=i+i^i^n?-1:n=i;);`?

Comment: @Titus I'm afraid that's not going to work in Java (although I have used [that approach in my iterative JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166277/52210)). In Java `i+i^i^n?` is not a boolean, so it won't even compile. In addition, `n>i-=...` will need parenthesis (`n>(i-=...)`), and `n=i` isn't allowed in the else-clause of the ternary-if, only in the if-clause (this last one I don't know why, but that's what it is in Java unfortunately).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen "and `n=i` isn't allowed in the else-clause of the ternary-if". Because Java would parse it as `(i-=(i*2^i)!=n?-1:n)=i` which is illegal.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, so that's why. Still, that's pretty stupid.. When would `(contains_ternary_if)=i` ever be valid to begin with. Java should just parse it differently imho.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:next((f(i)for i in range(n)if n==i^i*2),n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3NCsIwEITvPsUeE5lDfrq1KfRJRKFiowu6LaWH@vQxncPAfHwwy297zxpKycNn/D6eI2mv074Zk43YPK8kJErrqK/JqJVMOgxyl3OwUFsOQatwjWC0SPAOIaJjcJOQWldB3d4zw3MTkGrAl@i6o71H6qJjvvUnWlbRjXJ9KX8)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 53 bytes

```
f=x=>(i=0,y=(G=x=>x&&(i^=x&1)+2*G(x>>1))(x),i?x:f(y))
```

`G` is `g^-1`, which set `i` to `0` if success, set `i` to `1` if failed.

Comment: This was the approach I tried to use although I came up with a 50-byte version: `f=n=>(g=n=>n<2?0/!n:n%2+2*g(n/2^n%2))(n)?f(g(n)):n`. Sadly the boring approach is 12 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>13 12</s> 10 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @MrXcoder, and 2 more bytes following their suggestion*

```
fqQ.W<HQxy
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQ.W%3CHQxy&input=1023&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
fqQ.W<HQxyZZT   Implicit: Q=eval(input()), trailing ZZT inferred

f               Return the first T in [1,2,3...] where the following is truthy
   .W       T     Functional while - loop until condition is true, starting value T
     <HQ            Condition: continue while iteration value (H) less than input
        xyZZ        Body: xor iteration value (Z) with double (y) iteration value (Z)
 qQ               Is the result of the above equal to input?
```

Comment: You can drop the trailing `T` for 12 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>73</s>  65 bytes

```r
f=function(x){for(i in 1:x)if(x==bitwXor(i,i*2)){i=f(i);break};i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3dCoMwDEbvfYpcNqMDq6tzP77H7oZKC2GuG7Yyh/jsLh0bBr4EDod8/bLYyg6uDfRwYsTJPnpBQA7UcUSyYqyqhsLrErGkTYY4UWUF4anpTX2bTzQvwfhwbWtvPJy30IocJGhOwTlwVCohyyWUEerdgWmRRhyhUlrz1ruMMQ8b@zwtv0cpZmWeao1Jb/zQhW/D4DryQXT189m9xdouwSImrr4bL346Rn81/l@WDw)

Thanks a lot [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) (-8) due to your tweaks, so simple yet very effective

Comment: as opposed to a previous answer of yours, because this function is recursive, you _do_ need the `f=` since the function needs to be bound to `f` to work properly. That being said, nice work, and take a +1 from me!

Comment: you can also do some re-jiggering of your logic and get this to [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY3dCoMwDEbvfYpcNqMDq6tzP77H7oZKC2GuG7Yyh/jsLh0bBr4EDod8/bLYyg6uDfRwYsTJPnpBQA7UcUSyYqyqhsLrErGkTYY4UWUF4anpTX2bTzQvwfhwbWtvPJy30IocJGhOwTlwVCohyyWUEerdgWmRRhyhUlrz1ruMMQ8b@zwtv0cpZmWeao1Jb/zQhW/D4DryQXT189m9xdouwSImrr4bL346Rn81/l@WDw)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
f=(n,x=n)=>x?x^x+x^n?f(n,--x):f(x):n
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY3LCoMwFER/xUUXCd4Eo6Y0hehHdNlWEnwUxd6ISgmUfnuaLjuLgTlnMZN92a1dx2Vn6Lo@hEETBK@R6srXvvGpb7AeImPM0/NAYmFoHW5u7vnsHuRagIQjKBAZ5AWcJMhSgTpmEcQthJQgZJmDirnzp12I15U5vP3H8MV2l92uOylpahLGqsSkUf1u/i3lkxvR3NDQ8AU) - Starts throwing overflow errors somewhere between `9999` & `57308`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Use `⁺¿` to return the last non-zero element (thanks Dennis for -1 byte)

```
^Ḥ)i$⁺¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/u4Y4lmpkqjxp3Hdr//3D7o6Y1//9HG@uY6pjpWOoYGugYGetYmOqYmljqWJoZAAWAfENDU1MdQ1MTIx1LINAxNTc2sACRhoY6lhbGBqamsQA)

Brute force wins again :(

Comment: `^Ḥ)i$⁺¿` saves a byte.

Comment: And it's 2x slower.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>57</s> <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 51 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); `!=` ~ `-`.
- Saved <s>a byte</s> five bytes thanks to [Rogem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77406/rogem); making use of the ternary expression and gcc quirks.

```c
X(O,R){for(R=1;R;O=R?R:O)for(R=O;--R&&(R^2*R)-O;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7daoMwFMDx6/UpgsOSMyJ4orGmIfgIQuiFF2MgfozA5orurvTZnUu2lHW5OeHH4Z90yWvXrWtDa2bgMn7M1GhURtXaVOZYg5daJYnZ76l54U8GklqBuq6P/TDaaSAnatkM59lOnyONGhoXPRCtSSx6ois3aLzA8xQxyxpqgc1uaD1X0bldlqGPjtHY2rftAmr33tqJwmX3cKLk@2TMDYQg4p8UXvhNpJdDEEzvd7gvYxakvC@L3HWwCCIL3ynyH8HUd7L8dwdRuA4PZRQ5//u63M4mvETpRRyytGQEJfI8CKLrcN@RZZaK2w@v6xc)

Comment: `for(R=1;R;O=R?R:O)` saves a byte.

Comment: `R=O;` at the end seems to be unnecessary, saving you another 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 22 bytes

```
00000000: 1600 1803 4216 007a b830 097a 82aa b828  ....B..z.0.z...(
00000010: f314 18f3 78c9                           ....x.
```

Port of @KevinCruijssen's Java answer

[Example with input of 9-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcwxCsMwEATAPq/YMpVZSUY6p8xPZBmlMbgLQZ9XVrEfkIWDPbibZnwde@2dVx5g5IKycQVZIgLLpmZEii6qOQPD7IHpF2reozxvp@BkuEjd59X0Li1l88hj9VYD3CyjhmTDaBKa3u/D@FyGl1EW/Jep9y8)

[Example with input of 85-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BboMwEETP8BVz7CFCawjOJlIP7S0fkA8wdt1UcqAKpmr5eTK0fEBHsna8mnnaWeV9SHFZZNMJYtsWPkgHEW/RiA90KjhYY@mMQpp9DVSXihK@r9W8ln8EQ4axwrzrlHU50mkNt35rjQ3MnozYHJSMaiZhZv1pZXxvjJoMf8T/VC3Luf@c8rO25cs4vt269IM43BGn3uePoYd3KcH1AcOUGTyVY3Z3jiIFdDvWit9ELAsXAk@@bgvlKfRXl/ID)

Assembly:

```
;d=loop counter
;b=input and output
f:
	ld d,0
	jr loop
	begin:
	ld b,d
	ld d,0
	loop:
		ld a,d
		cp b
		jr nc,end	; if d==b end
		ld a,d
		add d		; mul by 2
		xor d
		cp b
		jr z,begin	; if (d*2)^d==b set b to d
		inc d
		jr loop
	end:
	ld a,b
	ret
```

Assembly example for calling the function and printing the result:

```
ld b,9 ; input to the function, in this case 9
call f
add 30h ; ASCII char '0'
call 8000h ; putchar
halt
```

Comment: If you make `a` the loop counter instead of `d`, then you can replace the `ld d,0` instructions by `xor a` both times, which saves two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Node.js), <s>48</s> <s>45</s> 38 bytes

```
f=(n,i=0)=>i<n?i*2^i^n?f(n,i+1):f(i):n
```

-7 bytes thanks to @Neil creating a recursive version of my iterative version below. Doesn't work for large test cases.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TczBDoIwDIDhO09BOG2iZgWGgA5exJAQBDJDOiOLrz/BZMWe/i1f@@w@3dK/9cue0DwG50bF8KiV4KrWN2z0IWl1i824/cbAq5FpXqGzw2JDFaKqe4OLmYfzbCaGcVTdbRSvmvNrEGyKpWv9QvrIfZQ@QPhKiBfkZUawzMW@s1sASRpklhBfh65cUlH8PQBIFanY9t0X)

---

Iterative **45 bytes** version that works for all test cases:

```
n=>{for(i=0;i<n;)i-=i*2^i^n?-1:n=i;return n;}
```

[Port of my Java answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166272/52210)
-3 bytes thanks to *@Arnauld*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TczRDoIgGIbhc6/CeYQ5G6iYStSNNDdn0GjupyF10rp20jYwjt5/ez7uw2uYR6MeNgd9FU5yB/z0ltogxTFTR2CpyrnaFb3q4ZyTDrhiRtingRjYx1kx25jHy2jUMOtJ7Cd9Q5Al3cUmmUSQpiyKVoXKpX5BfdQ@Wh8E@yoCb4KnVYBtjbfNZgmhQRNaFYEvL/xyKHHzdxASVFPide@@)

Comment: You can do `i-=i*2^i^n?-1:n=i` (but unfortunately not in Java).

Comment: @Arnauld Figured something was possible for the boolean in Java to just `1` in JS. Thanks!

Comment: 38 bytes written recursively (doesn't work for larger inputs): `f=(n,i=0)=>i<n?i*2^i^n?f(n,i+1):f(i):n`

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
BÄḂṛḄß$Ṫ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/pcMvDHU0Pd85@uKPl8HyVhztX2f8/3P6oac3//9HGOqY6ZjqWOoYGOkbGOhamOqYmljqWZgZAASDf0NDUVMfQ1MRIxxIIdEzNjQ0sQKShoY6lhbGBqWksAA)

Tips: Use recursive function instead of loops.

---

Very fast, unfortunately loses to the brute force approach.

Note that:

- For *x > 0*, *f(x) > x*.
- *popcount(f(x))* is even, where *popcount(n)* is the number of bits set in *n*.
- If *n* has even popcount, then there exists *x* such that  *f(x) = n*.
- Let *B(x)* be the binary representation of *x*, and *Ṗ(l)* be the list *l* with last element removed. Then *B(x)* is the accumulated XOR of *Ṗ(B(f(x)))*.

So, we repeatedly:

- Compute its binary representation (`B`)
- then take the accumulated XOR (use `^\` or `ÄḂ`, they have the same effect).
- Check if (`?`) the tail (last element) (`Ṫ`) of the accumulated XOR is nonzero (odd popcount)

  - If so, convert the binary list back to decimal and recurse.
  - If not, returns the input (`ṛ`).

Comment: 9 bytes: [`B^\⁸Ḅß$Ṫ?`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98pLuZR446HO1oOz1d5uHOV/f/D7Y@a1vz/H22sY6pjpmOpY2igY2SsY2GqY2piqWNpZgAUAPINDU1NdQxNTYx0LIFAx9Tc2MACRBoa6lhaGBuYmsYCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>32</s> 26 bytes

```
{$[*|a:2!+\2\x;x;2/-1_a]}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvdCoJAFITve4oTBGkh7jn7467nUVLSGyMMA/FCKXv17ezAwDDfzFhMjynGof6cbpdvX9Px2lCz8spUFnjv272MS4Lbb64HWLl7j5x1Q/98yWbjOW/3w1KeMw3IVuyAOEDFqCSQtJp96q0JgA45OAXOCBamDTKitUCyQmsofUVAHgPbSisPGJBMyohApDl4reSBefwD)

`{` `}` is a function with argument `x`

`/` applies it until convergence

`$[` `;` `;` `]` if-then-else

`2\x` binary digits of `x` (this is specific to ngn/k)

`+\` partial sums

`2!` mod 2

`a:` assign to `a`

`*|` last - reverse (`|`) and get first (`*`)

if the above is 1, `x` will be returned

otherwise:

`-1_a` drop the last element of `a`

`2/` decode binary

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 78 bytes

```java
int g(int n){return f(n)%2<1?g(f(n)/2):n;}int f(int x){return 1>x?0:x^f(x/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFfa4MwFMXf@ykuhUJCmUu0dlbH@gn21Mf9gaxVSWvTYq6dQ/zsLhFZk@UhyQnn/ALnHsVNPBwPp2FfCa3hVUjVDVIhlMTuinZ1jk2toCCKLsJnvi2JvT6GNFVZbz3F6Gz/nPyl3bK0/SxIa1xZP2SzGcC1@arkHjQKNMftIg9wNp@RHdZSlW8fIGhnbACYayQRze4idsXaFRtXcOaq0EMkHiNeecHNmvkcP8t57KV5vAq9uFke/Sliyb8Hzr1EErGJ2dtu3FJGgy1UTn3sfjTm5@DSYHA1VWGlCMjlPH3H@RJU/j3OjNDADIzCxOyHXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>g(n)%2?n:f(g(n)/2)
g=x=>x&&x^g(x/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczRCoMgGIbh864igoUS29SyVcN2I2MQzWIjdCwZ3r3TgX/z6FWez@fwGdbx/XiZvdJ36dwklOhnpPCOXVQ3oZBHhpNZWNHbPLe3GVn/4IxcTSpSr0etVr3Iw6I9LrLuarJi8jN8TpKgUOnrFzxGHaONQUksBrwBzyuAbU22zWYp5aAprxhwf@CXU0mavwuloJqShL37Ag)

Thanks Shaggy for -1 bytes.

Port of my [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166281/69850).

Finally there is a language where this approach is <s>shorter</s> ([oops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166285/69850)). (I tried Python and [Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166283), it doesn't work)

Can anyone explain why I can use `/2` instead of `>>1`?

Comment: `x/2` works because of arithmetic underflow. Any IEEE 754 number will eventually be evaluated as **0** when divided by 2 enough times. (And the decimal part is simply ignored when XOR'd, so this does not affect the result.)

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##TczRCoMgGIbh864igoUS29SyVcN2I2MQzWIjdCwZ3r3TgX/z6FWez@fwGdbx/XiZvdJ36dwklOhnpPCOXVQ3oZBHhpNZWNHbPLe3GVn/4IxcTSpSr0etVr3Iw6I9LrLuarJi8jN8TpKgUOnrFzxGHaONQUksBrwBzyuAbU22zWYp5aAprxhwf@CXU0mavwuloJqShL37Ag)

Comment: @Shaggy Surprised that it works. I know it works for Python and Lua etc., but not Javascript.

Comment: The `false` returned on the last iteration is implicitly cast to `0` by the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: @Shaggy In fact, [no `false` is involved](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP13DQEFNTcFAkwtDrCQjszgeiPLyS@JTyxJzShNLUlM0NFFVGoFUGmv@/w8A). JS `&&` behaves almost identically to Python/Lua `and`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
f=->x,y=x{y<1?x:x==y^y*2?f[y]:f[x,y-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNCsIwEEb3OUXAnTTSyZ9JMe1BQgUVg0vRFhJaz17TqDTY2czwZnh8zKM/h2lyhtS@CMYP4QCNr7wx4Ri2tHE2tJWzcUegfU0Wx2K42BBSzyMGlJpYI5kh@kE6Q/uEoFxd0UwPLCG10gu@uEAmpGXmkhzN8szF@HwFIBYXTXoQnP6F0LF@iCrQCIs9K9UXgQbKEwJYXJQhrVgZ9TiL2u6up8ttGLvx3ndP7GwXn/gG)

As expected for the recursive version, complains about "stack level too deep" on the latter test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 71 bytes

```forth
: f 0 begin 2dup dup 2* xor = if nip 0 else 1+ then 2dup < until drop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzhDoIwDIT/8xQXfmpG2NyIiPowygZLyLaMkfj22KJNvja9u9bFXGYxOR77foNDi5edfIAatwRGnfCJGQ94h@ATBeyyWsgzymz/uTu2UPyCMceEgf78TjWajKYGhHjW9Nvw/s4YqgtSZYiO6AnZUlOsXlk2msW@aw/r0KU07EijFVtUSPsX)

#### Explanation

```forth
0                 \ add an index variable to the top of the stack
begin             \ start an indefinite loop
  2dup            \ duplicate the top two stack items (n and i)
  dup 2* xor =    \ calculate i xor 2i and check if equal to n
  if nip 0        \ if equal, drop n (making i the new n) and use 0 as the new i
  else 1+         \ otherwise just increment i by 1
  then            \ end the if-statement
  2dup <          \ duplicate the top two stack items and check if n < i
until             \ if previous statement is true, end the loop
drop              \ drop i, leaving n on top of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 44 bytes

```perl6
{({first {($^a+^2*$a)==$_},^$_}...^!*).tail}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##XY5daoQwFEbfs4pbkKKjkzHROKZi6SL6WCxWMyD4hzqlRVxRd9GN2SSjMvU@JHDyfeemFV0ZzNdewGeAswih6hsesyYXEM@jOV6Krh9gNI0ktRN6MFIrjo33yUnkgTFOHg4WHtKinGbZexmEDMdQFrXocZW2TzDavz84a6oP8/SW2yfLAVlESO17leEItWVag62bEbo03SI5PoNpGkXdXgfHEF@tyAaRq3Yu@syCEQEUPah/Lin1tuaWWISmGdR4cJQ@NQTpi@1BsAF6A3wDZw2Iu0vQTUo8DcKdlPmrgwQa8GBzBD5Sys3h@SpBCFsdVEsJ8@m/tVzODdCQcATs7LmhBoQT6mtAyOqgHuKh57K7j/0B)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  (
    # generate a sequence

    # no need to seed the sequence with $_, as the following block will
    # default to using the outer $_
    # $_, 

    { # parameter $_

      first
        {  # block with placeholder parameter $a

          ( $^a +^ 2 * $a ) # double (numeric) xor
          == $_             # is it equal to the previous value
        },

        ^$_  # Range up to and excluding the previous value ( 0..^$_ )
    }

    ...^  # keep doing that until: (and throw away last value)

    !*    # it doesn't return a trueish value

  ).tail  # return the last generated value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 44 bytes

```
A-R:-between(1,A,B),A is B xor(B*2),B-R;R=A.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsMgEEX3PYXLWJzgaExNSwl6BI9QkCKEWEzA3t527/zlW7z3PyVv@Q1HTa05CHd4xbPGuA8onPBcOJYO5tk3l8FfFRcewiM83dhW0BAEqyWdcduHwMfLCqZHc4@WHqHsmSICliiYiRAus6QqlBPREFY0kyK0/xEPblpaEiMSDqtlV2w/)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 49 bytes

Based on Kevin Cruijssen's answers.

```php
for($x=$argn;$x>$i-=$i*2^$i^$x?-1:$x=$i;);echo$x;
```

Run as pipe with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c3a9d770bce01dc8b29b8a2efee8420a062ab60).

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 92 bytes

```
let rec o i=
 let r=Seq.tryFind(fun x->x^^^x*2=i){1..i-1}
 if r.IsNone then i else o r.Value
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZBBS8NAEIXv@RWPQsEK2WaTpqbE5KYgiAhCL7WBkE7qQNzUzUYi6m@Pk9q5DPMxvHlv6s6vWkvj2JCDpQotOPNwnrIX@lDOft2zOVzVvcHg50NRFMN1mPHiWyvFvv71wDWseuieWkNwb2TAoKYjkbJqWzY9jbvbOyNCzy0bl@@9Sf29ZIPSHj9xOcfm1LsOGXZRijjFOsUmhQ5ShAISIfFKwGYdTHRiWsdCdbwKBUvJxk0UJOemtbAkCuJ47@GRO6fYkcV/DPi5mBvwk@NkxVJtMJvzq5vzDMPi4sRDgOVSfuJ6K04llXF0FA0a2KFqDzT@AQ)

Recursively checks through the numbers from 1 to `i-1`. If there's a match, check for a smaller for that number. If there's no match, return the input number.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 62 bytes

Based on Kevin Cruijssen's Java:

`int n(int j){for(int i=0;i<j;)i-=(i*2^i)==j?j=i:-1;return j;}`

To test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n(int j);
#define p(i) printf("%6d --> %5d\n", i, n(i))
int main(void)
{
    p(3);
    p(5);
    p(6);
    p(9);
    p(10);
    p(23);
    p(85);
    p(549);
    p(960);
    p(1023);
    p(1155);
    p(1542);
    p(9999);
    p(57308);
    p(57311);
    p(983055);
}
```

When run, the test program outputs:

```
     3 -->     1
     5 -->     1
     6 -->     2
     9 -->     7
    10 -->     2
    23 -->    13
    85 -->     1
   549 -->   161
   960 -->    64
  1023 -->   341
  1155 -->   213
  1542 -->     2
  9999 -->  2819
 57308 --> 19124
 57311 -->   223
983055 -->     1
```

## C, 54 bytes

Only works with C89 or K&R C:

`n(j){for(i=0;i<j;)i-=(i*2^i)==j?j=i:-1;return j;}`

Comment: `int n(int j){for(int i=0;j>i-=i*2^i^j?-1:j=i;);return j;}` Do these 57 bytes work?

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 58 bytes

```
Min[{#}//.x_:>Select[Range@#,MemberQ[x,#|BitXor[#,2#]]&]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d83My@6WrlWX1@vIt7KLjg1JzW5JDooMS891UFZxzc1Nym1KDC6Qke5ximzJCK/KFpZx0g5NlYNiP7rOyhUG@somOoomOkoWOooGBroKBgBBSyAIqYmQAFLMwOQqJFxbex/AA)

Starts with a list containing just the input. Iteratively replaces the list by all integers that are either already in it, or map into it by the double-and-xor operation. Then `//.` says to do this until reaching a fixed point. The answer is the least element of the result.